# How to insert a key to only one side of a bimap in c++

Tags: c++, boost

I need to do something similar using bimap with what can be done using normal maps e.g.

```
std:map<int, std::string> mymap;

mymap[1];

if(mymap.find(1))
    mymap[1] = "demo";
```

Similar code that I've been trying:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>

int main()
{
   typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::set_of<std::string>, boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>> key_to_id_bimap_t;
   typedef key_to_id_bimap_t::value_type value_type;
   key_to_id_bimap_t bimap;
   
   bimap.right[1];
   
   if(bimap.right.find(1))
   {
       // insert a bunch of value into bimap
   }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't the sense of a bimap to manage bi-directional relations?

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenter says, because the maps are "synced" you cannot expect to edit the value of one side, because it **is** the key of the other side.

The documentation has a very similar example that highlights these impossibilities [see my highlight in "`operator[]` and `at()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/differences_with_standard_maps.html#boost_bimap.the_tutorial.differences_with_standard_maps.operator_____and_at__#:%7E:text=bm.right%5B1%5D%20=%20%22one%22;%20//%20compilation%20error) in the ["Differences with standard maps"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/differences_with_standard_maps.html)

I tend to favour MultiIndex. It has the same essential limitations/semantics, but it has fewer surprises for my taste because it handles it explicitly. Of course the downside is that you have to specify your indexes manually.

### MultiIndex Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bf55436dbcc928b)**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

struct Entry {
    std::string key;
    int id;
};
using Map = bmi::multi_index_container<Entry,
      bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct by_key>,
            bmi::member<Entry, std::string, &Entry::key> >,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct by_id>,
            bmi::member<Entry, int, &Entry::id> >
      > >;

void dump(std::string_view caption, Map const& bimap) {
    std::cout << caption << ":";
    for (auto& [key,id] : bimap) {
        std::cout << " {" << std::quoted(key) << ", " << id << "}";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Map bimap;

    auto& left = bimap.get<by_key>();
    auto& right = bimap.get<by_id>();

    // insertions through any index, or just `bumap` which will be the first
    // idex
    right.insert(Entry { "foo", 11 });
    right.insert(Entry { "bar", 22 });
    right.insert(Entry { "qux", 33 });
    assert(bimap.size() == 3);

    auto [it, ok] = right.insert(Entry { "foo", 23 });
    assert(!ok);
    assert(bimap.size() == 3);

    dump("Before", bimap);

    // looking for a single match:
    if (auto it = left.find("foo"); it != left.end()) {
        // to add more relations just insert,
        // to replace the one match found:
        bool ok = left.replace(it, {"something else", it->id}); // okay

        assert(ok);
        assert(it->key == "something else");

        ok = left.replace(it, {"foo", 22}); // id doesn't need to be unique

        assert(ok);
        assert(it->key == "foo");
        ok = left.replace(it, {"bar", 77}); // whoops, duplicate

        assert( ! ok);
        assert(it->key == "foo"); // unchanged
        assert(it->id == 22); // unchanged
    }

    dump("First edit", bimap);

    // query multiple
    for (auto [it,end] = right.equal_range(22); it != end; ++it) {
        // to add more relations just insert,
        // to operate on the match
        bool ok = right.modify(it, [](Entry& match) {
                    match.key = "twenty-two: " + match.key;
                });
        assert(ok);
    }

    dump("Second edit", bimap);
}
```

Prints

```
Before: {"bar", 22} {"foo", 11} {"qux", 33}
First edit: {"bar", 22} {"foo", 22} {"qux", 33}
Second edit: {"qux", 33} {"twenty-two: bar", 22} {"twenty-two: foo", 22}
```

### Notes, Conclusion:

As you can see Multi-Index adopts the `replace`/`modify` idioms. Note that `modify` can be a more efficient way to update but it is less "atomic" (check the documentation on how it behaves on conflict).